# iPhone app version number in X.01

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

Can we not upload an app version x.01 in apple store. Its automatically changing it to x.1. I have a current version x.0 live in apple store. I have a minor update to the app so I changed the version as x.01 and uploaded in the iTunes connect. It automatically changed it to x.1 after processing it.

Please help.

Comment: try setting it to X.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Zeros before numbers after a point are ignored. (ie : x.00001 = x.1)

What you probably want is version x.0.1.

Comment: If I recall correctly you have a field called something like app information where you can change the version of a **PENDING** review version. If the version was already launched you can't change it. If you can't find that field you can always delete/launch new version. Again, if that version isn't already in the app store.

Answer (score 0):

I think Tiago's answer explains why your zero is missing. I would also suggest using a versioning scheme with 2 decimal points, like the one described here: http://semver.org/

This gives you more control to differentiate between a small feature update and a bug fix, even though neither warrant incrementing the first digit of your version number.